# SQL merging columns where only one column differ

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I use SQL Server 2017 and have a simple query with joins that looks like this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    [p].[MainTitle] AS Title,
    [pe].[Name] AS JobName,
    [ea].[Label] AS Stat
FROM
    [Project] AS [P]
INNER JOIN 
    [ProjectExtended] AS [pe] ON [p].[ID] = [pe].[ProjectID]
INNER JOIN 
    [ExtAttributes] AS [ea] ON [pe].[AttributeID] = [ea].[ID]
      ...
WHERE 
    pe.date BETWEEN @start AND @end
    AND [ea].Label IN ('A', 'B', 'C')
```

The result right know looks like this (`JobName` is different for every `Title` but always the same for the same `Title`)

```
+-----------+----------+--------------+
| Title     | JobName  | Stat         | 
+-----------+----------+--------------+
|      BAMB | asdf     |  C           | 
|      BIRT | fdsa     |  B           | 
|      BIRT | fdsa     |  A           |
|      BOND | lofe     |  B           |
+-----------+----------+--------------+
```

But I want it to show like this.

```
+-----------+----------+--------------+
| Title     | JobName  | Stat         | 
+-----------+----------+--------------+
|      BAMB | asdf     |  C           |
|      BIRT | fdsa     |  B, A        |
|      BOND | lofe     |  B           |
+-----------+----------+--------------+
```

I tried with different versions of `CONCAT`, `STRING_AGG` functions that you suggested in different threads, but no success. I only got to the point where it joins all the stats in last column - result was like A, B, C in every row.

Comment: What version of SQLS?

Comment: Why are you doing `FULL OUTER JOIN [ExtAttributes]` when you specified in `WHERE` clause `[ea].Label IN (...)` . Effectively you are only doing an `INNER JOIN` to that table

Comment: Also `IN ('A', 'B', 'C', NULL)` You will not get any row return with `Label` having `NULL` value. Not very sure what are you trying to do here

Answer (score 2):

This should help:

```sql
SELECT 
    [t].[Title] AS Title,
    [t].[JobName] AS JobName,
    STRING_AGG([t].[Stat], ',') AS Stat
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        [p].[MainTitle] AS Title,
        [pe].[Name] AS JobName,
        [ea].[Label] AS Stat
    FROM
        [Project] AS [P]
    INNER JOIN 
        [ProjectExtended] AS [pe] ON [p].[ID] = [pe].[ProjectID]
    FULL OUTER JOIN 
        [ExtAttributes] AS [ea] ON [pe].[AttributeID] = [ea].[ID]
        ...
    WHERE 
        pe.date BETWEEN @start AND @end
        AND [ea].Label IN ('A', 'B', 'C', NULL)
) t
GROUP BY 
[t].[Title]
, [t].[JobName]
```

It says version 15 but hopefully is available on yours also
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: This is in the docs - header line: "Applies to: SQL Server 2017 (14.x) and later" - so it *should* be available and work for the OP

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your help, but this solution still returns wrong results. For example, I got something like C, C, C in first row and A, B, A, B in second row.

Comment: Hi @baller, so you would like only to have the `DISTINCT` values?

Comment: Yes @RuiCosta, I'd only like DISTINCT values in Stat column...

Comment: Can you check the new EDIT?